# How to take a screenshot of the current widget and save in gallery- Flutter

Tags: flutter

How do I use flutter to save the screenshot to the gallery (android)?

I am new to flutter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating raw image from Widget or Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41957086/creating-raw-image-from-widget-or-canvas)

Answer (score 0):

refer to my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62993541/11276416), add global key to your root widget. Save image with this package, [gallery_saver](https://pub.dev/packages/gallery_saver).

```
GallerySaver.saveImage(imgFile.path).then((String path) {
          setState(() {
            firstButtonText = 'image saved!';
          });
        });
```

Comment: Hi Jim, I want to take a screenshot and I have it inside a RepaintBoundary. Please can you show how to get the screenshot with onPressed method on RaiseButton. Thanks in advance.

Comment: this will be the method inside onPressed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62993541/11276416